# populating combo box on run time

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, combobox

I got two combo box on the system a Category and Sub Category

my concept must be when i choose COM OR PRT on cmbCategory,

cmbSubCategory will automatically display the corresponding subcategory for the category chosen

```
Private Sub cmbCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbCategory.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cmbCategory.Text = "COM" Then
            cmbSubCategory.Items = "SU, MON"
        End If
    End Sub
```

my code returns error

Property Items is Read Only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx) is a collection so to put things into it you need to add them to the collection rather than direct assignment.

If `SU` and `MON` are meant to appear as separate items in the combo box then you could do something similar to:

```
Private Sub cmbCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbCategory.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cmbCategory.Text = "COM" Then
        cmbSubCategory.Items.Clear()
        cmbSubCategory.Items.Add("SU")
        cmbSubCategory.Items.Add("MON")
    End If
End Sub
```

If `SU, MON` is meant to appear as a single item then you could do:

```
Private Sub cmbCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbCategory.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cmbCategory.Text = "COM" Then
        cmbSubCategory.Items.Clear()
        cmbSubCategory.Items.Add("SU, MON")
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that we use [Clear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.clear.aspx) to remove items from the combo box/ensure it is empty before populating it with the right options.

**PS.** I noticed that one of the tags for this question is "SQL", but from what I've read I don't think that this question has a SQL component to it...

Comment: my system is connected sir to sql, but i wont be using codes complicated codes to call sql data to populate combo box. so i can manipulate the system easily. thanks for the answer ill be trying the code sir feedback later

Comment: Thanks. Because this specific question isn't directly SQL related (just for VB.NET code) I'll remove the SQL tag so it doesn't cause confusion for other users on SO....

Comment: thank you very much sir, the code is working fine! ill be revising it again for other purposes